# .bash_profile not being read

Tags: centos, bash, centos6, bashrc

So I am using CentOS 6.3 a fresh install and I was trying to add things to my path for OpenMPI so I edited my .bash_profile file to read:

```
FOO='test'
export FOO

# Add support for MPI
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin




export PATH
```

Which apparently isn't being read when I start up a bash shell, my $PATH is without the /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin path and FOO doesn't exist when I try to `echo $FOO`

.bashrc is read just fine and if I do `source ~/.bash_profile` FOO is created as well as my $PATH being edited properly but it will not run .bash_profile on its own so if I could get any help that would be great.

Answer (score 13):

Could you describe how do you test these 2 files? Did you try login or non-login shell? Here is the difference:

When you login your system and see the command line prompt, it’s a login shell, and it executes these files in order:

```
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
/etc/bashrc
```

A non-login shell will only execute the two files in order:

```
/etc/bashrc
~/.bashrc
```

If you just simply start a bash shell by "bash", it is a non-login shell and ~/.bash_profile will not be invoked. If you expect the variables to be set even when running non-login shell, you should put them into `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: It doesn't execute .bashrc if .bash_profile doesn't say so. On my system, for my account, .bash_profile didn't exist, so .bashrc was never executed.

Answer (score 4):

This is [normal](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html), .bash_profile is sourced for login shells, .bashrc is sourced for interactive non-login shells. In CentOS the top of .bash_profile usually has:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

So you can put things in .bashrc.

Mac OS X Terminal reads .bash_profile when you open a new windows. gnome-terminal can be made to do that with [Run command as a login shell](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-prefs.html.en#gnome-terminal-prefs-title).